# Why can my lambda expressions not use the same internal variable?

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and was working with these lambda values.

My question is Why can the parameter list not be the same variable in each of them? If you notice in print (q is the variable) and in square (c is the variable) and in add (x, y) are the variables and in IsLessThanTen (f is the variable) what if I wanted to make them all the same parameter name, like say Pizza can this be done. It was on the tutorial I was watching. My second minor question is how would this make the code better if you rather than just using a regular function?

I think that these are called Lambda expression. I heard a couple of different names on the tutorial video.

**Question: Can the same variable be used in different lambda expressions?**

I want to know if I can say use the variable index in all of my lambda expressions

```
  Action<int> print = index => Console.Writeline(index);
```

Code:

```
Action<bool> print = q => Console.WriteLine(q);
Func<double, double> square = c => c * c;
Func<double, double, double> add = (x, y) => x + y;
Predicate<double> isLessThanTen = f => f < 10;

print(isLessThanTen(square(add(4, 5))));

Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you asking if you can reuse the same variable in separate lambda expressions (outside of the same closure of course), or use it in the same one? Could you provide an example of what you think should work that doesn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your second question.  A benefit of using delegates like this is that the function represented by the delegate can be changed at runtime.

For example, let's say you have a delegate for `multiply`

```
Func<double, double, double> multiply = (a, b) => a * b;
```

And let's say, you have a crazy requirement to divide instead of multiply if a certain condition is met.

So...

```
if(crazyDemandIsMet){
   multiply = (a, b) => a / b;
}
```

Now, everywhere you use multiply, it will actually divide.

In this instance, think of `multiply` as a variable that holds a function and can be called as a function.  To change the value of this "variable", you have to assign it to a function that matches the signature that you defined.

I've used delegates in the past when using multiple types of databases in one solution.  The delegates would be different depending on if the database was Oracle or MS SQL.

Comment: So in reality you can change the delegate function depending on a condition on the fly. So in one case it might add or divide in another case. With a regular function you could not do this but would have to call a different function altogether.

Comment: Exactly, which results in much cleaner code.  Also, keep in mind that you don't have to use a lambda.  You can assign a declared function to a delegate as well, as long as it matches the signature.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the lambda parameter names can be reused and the duplicate variable names won't clash "across" sibling [Lambda Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) (aka anonymous function) ..

```
Action<bool> print = q => Console.WriteLine(q);
Func<double, double> square = q => q * q;
Func<double, double, double> add = (q, q2) => q + q2;
Predicate<double> isLessThanTen = q => q < 10;
```

.. even if it can lead to *harder* to understand code! As Servy commented,

> Of course, if each parameter conceptually represents the same thing, then using the same parameter name is fine. *It's using the same parameter name to represent entirely different things that's a problem.*

That is, the `q` in each lambda is a *separate* variable, even if they share the same name.

---

Now, there are cases that are not allowed, primarily when a variable with the same name exists in an *outer* scope (in the question the naming sharing was in *sibling* scopes). For instance,

```
int q = 0;
Action<bool> print = q => Console.WriteLine(q);
```

results in a compiler error

> A local variable named 'q' cannot be declared in this scope
>     because it would give a different meaning to 'q', which is already used
>     in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else.

---

Some big benefits of lambda expressions, as compared to normal methods:

1. Lambdas expressions can result in [Expression Trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) - this is *the* magic behind L2S/EF.
2. As compared to normal methods, lambdas can act as closures and capture free variables.
3. Sweet, sweet sugar. Very useful when applied with the above in LINQ queries.

Comment: Of course, if each parameter conceptually represents the same thing, then using the same parameter name is fine.  It's using the same parameter name to represent entirely different things that's a problem.

Comment: @Servy Very nice. I quoted your comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same variable name in different lambdas, but they have to be unique in the method in which they're contained. For example:

```
void SomeFunction()
{
    int i;
    Func<int, int> timesTwo = i => i * 2;  // Bad. Conflicts with other variable
}
```

As to your other question, whether or not they're better than a regular method, that's totally subjective and they both have their place.

Comment: As per my tests, lambdas also are faster than function calls, I supose because they are already delegates

Comment: @Gusman False and false.  Lambdas are not delegates.  They are one possible syntax used for creating instances of a delegate.  Lambdas will be compiled into named methods, just like any other named method; that name simply isn't known until the code is compiled.  You won't know what the name is, but the method will actually have a name at runtime.  Odds are very high that your tests are flawed in some way; either you aren't comparing equivalent operations, or you're improperly measuring them.  Both are very easy to do, as benchmarking is a hard thing to do properly.

Comment: Nope, tested a lot of times because I was expecting oposite results, and calling a lambda function (or a delegate from a function) is faster. What I mean with "are delegates" is that you will use it from a delegate (when you asign it to a var a delegate is created), you cannot call it like a pure function.

Comment: @Gusman Saying that you've tested it means nothing.  As I said, benchmarking code is hard, virtually nobody does it properly.  You almost certainly weren't comparing what you thought you were comparing, and/or measuring it properly.  Your attempted explanation of what's going on also makes it clear you *don't* understand what's going on.

Comment: Hi again. This really interests me, I have redone tests again and actions vs functions gave me faster results. Would love to share the test to see if something is wrong about it, but i don't think a comment is the right place, maybe I should create a new question?

Comment: @Servy I created a question with the test case and results, please review it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the same variable name for all of the lambda methods.

```
        Action<bool>                 method1 = i => Console.WriteLine(i);
        Func<double, double>         method2 = i => i * i;
        Func<double, double, double> method3 = (i, i2) => i + i2 / i * i *40;
        Predicate<double>            method4 = i => i < 2000;
```

You cannot have a local variable called i that would result in a naming conversion. The reason that people use these types of expressions is because they are faster in some cases and you can change them on the fly depending on a condition

```
        Action<int>  method1 = i => Console.WriteLine(i + 3);

        if (test == 3)
             method1 = i => Console.WriteLine(i + i);
        else if (test == 2)
             method1 = i => Console.WriteLine(i + i + i);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

You see above the method1 has been defined above but based on the test result the method1 can be changed to something different. You could do the same thing with two different methods if you wanted to. I am some times not certain were one should use this type of example. I have seen it in code on times but then frankly it seems strange to me to decide when to use it because you could make ever function in your code just like the above examples.